# negative value problem in array in korn shell

Tags: shell, ksh

When I try to create an array containing a negative value, it's throws the following error.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

set -A sre_act_val -0.1429999999999998 0.44700000000000006

echo "${sre_act_val[1]}"
echo "${sre_act_val[0]}"
```

Error:

```
set: -0: unknown option
set: -.: unknown option
set: -1: unknown option
set: -4: unknown option
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that ksh interprets anything starting with a dash as an option (at least for `set`), so it reads `-0.143` as a series of options: `0`, `.`, `1`, `4`, and `3`.

To get around this, you can use `--` before any of the array elements to tell ksh to stop interpreting arguments. This is documented in the `man` page for ksh, in the section for the `set` built-in.

```
set -A sre_act_val -- -0.1429999999999998 0.44700000000000006
echo "${sre_act_val[@]}" # output: -0.1429999999999998 0.44700000000000006
```

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the check mark under the up-/down-vote buttons.